# how to pass csrf token in all views in express, nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, express, csrf

I have a NodeJS app built using ExpressJS. After a security review, I was suggested to implement CSRF on all forms and ajax submissions. For this, I used [csurf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/csurf) package. For this, we need to pass CSRF token in every form page, then return it with form submission data.

First, I tried doing this individually for pages that contained forms. But later I realised that I had a search form in my page header, which appears on all of the pages. Now, is there any way I can pass the CSRF token, to all my views, without passing it explicitly for each request. Here's a general code I use for rendering my form pages. I use Jade/Pug for rendering:

```
router.get('/createcampaign', checkUserSession, middleWare2, middleware3, function(req, res){
    var pageInfo = {};
    pageInfo.title = 'Create New Campaign';
    pageInfo.projects = req.projects;
    pageInfo.session = req.session;
    pageInfo.bodyid = 'createcampaign';
    pageInfo.project_id = req.flash('project_id');
    pageInfo.bodyclass = 'bluebody';
    pageInfo.account = req.account;
    pageInfo.grammars = req.grammars;
    pageInfo.csrfToken = req.csrfToken; //Here I pass csrfToken to view

    res.render( 'users/createcampaign', pageInfo );
});//createcampaign get route
```

As you can see, I need to pass csrfToken with view context object. **How can I pass it globally so it will be passed to all views?**

**Also, is it safe security wise, to send this csrfToken on all pages and use it wherever required?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
create a middleware that will pass a token to the token property to the request object
var csrf = require('csurf')   
app.use(csrf())
app.use(function(request,response,next){
    app.locals._token = request.csrfToken()
    next() 
})

and you can use the variable _token in your view
```

Comment: Thanks @yvesdaxmaz. I did something similar, but I used `res.locals` instead of `app.locals`. Can you suggest which one is better and should be used?

Comment: res.locals is restrict to the request that has concerned on the other hand  app.locals is available in all of your template

Comment: all of them are similar and can be use for the same purpose the difference is that I give in the above comment.

Comment: thanks Yvesdaxmaz. Can you please also suggest if there is any security vulnerability in passing csrf token to all views, even where it is not needed.

Comment: No there isn't vulnerability, but csrf token are very important only when there is some form on the page, and we want to be protect from data that are submit.  there isn't valid reason to use it when there isn't any form on the page.